# Javascript - How to create filtered nested Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have my array object here:

```
let businessList = [{
  name: "siAdmin",
  count: 52,
  children: [{
    name: "si1",
    count: 30,
    children: [{
      count: 10,
      name: "org1-1"
    }, {
      count: 14,
      name: "org1-2"
    }, {
      name: "org1-3",
      count: 6
    }]
  }, {
    name: "si2",
    count: 22,
    children: [{
      name: "org2-1",
      count: 22
    }]
  }]
}]
```

I want to make make a filtered list if `count > 10`, which would be like:

```
filteredList = [{
  name: "siAdmin",
  count: 52,
  children: [{
    name: "si1",
    count: 30,
    children: [{
      count: 14,
      name: "org1-2"
    }]
  }, {
    name: "si2",
    count: 22,
    children: [{
      name: "org2-1",
      count: 22
    }]
  }]
}]
```

How can I achieve this result?

And if condition changes to `count > 23`, it would be like:

```
filteredList = [{
  name: "siAdmin",
  count: 52,
  children: [{
    name: "si1",
    count: 30,
    children: []
  }]
}]
```

Comment: What did you try share with us

Comment: Shell this si2 be in children?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find the solution without breaking the original object, here's my code:

```
let businessList = [{
  name: "siAdmin",
  count: 52,
  children: [{
    name: "si1",
    count: 30,
    children: [{
      count: 10,
      name: "org1-1"
    }, {
      count: 14,
      name: "org1-2"
    }, {
      name: "org1-3",
      count: 6
    }]
  }, {
    name: "si2",
    count: 22,
    children: [{
      name: "org2-1",
      count: 22
    }]
  }]
}];

function filteredBusiness(businessArr, count) {
  let arr = [];
  businessArr.forEach((business) => {
    let index = 0;
    let businessMatched = business.count > count
    if (businessMatched) {
      let {
        children,
        ...dataWithoutChildren
      } = business;
      arr.push({
        ...dataWithoutChildren
      });
      index = arr.length - 1;
      let hasChildren = business.children;
      if (hasChildren) {
        // arr[index].children = [];
        //check children matched
        let nextBusinessArr = filteredBusiness(
          business.children,
          count
        );
        if (nextBusinessArr) {
          arr[index].children = nextBusinessArr;
        }
      }
    }
  })
  return arr;
}
console.log(filteredBusiness(businessList, 10))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use recursion like this,

```js
let businessList = [{
  name: "siAdmin",
  count: 52,
  children: [{
    name: "si1",
    count: 30,
    children: [{
      count: 10,
      name: "org1-1"
    }, {
      count: 14,
      name: "org1-2"
    }, {
      name: "org1-3",
      count: 6
    }]
  }, {
    name: "si2",
    count: 22,
    children: [{
      name: "org2-1",
      count: 22
    }]
  }]
}];

const filteredArray = (arr, countLimit) => {
  return arr.filter(item => {
    if(item.hasOwnProperty('children')) {
      item.children = filteredArray(item.children, countLimit);
    }
    return item.count > countLimit;
  })
};

console.log(filteredArray(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(businessList)), 10));
console.log(filteredArray(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(businessList)), 23));

console.log(businessList);
```

Comment: this is not working becauses it will mess up original businessList in

`item.children = filteredArray(item.children, countLimit)` part.

I think the push method is the only solution for me.

Comment: You can create a new copy of businessList and then filter that copy array to keep your businessList intact.

Comment: @RyanHsin updated the code please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

```
    let businessList = [{
  name: "siAdmin",
  count: 52,
  children: [{
    name: "si1",
    count: 30,
    children: [{
      count: 10,
      name: "org1-1"
    }, {
      count: 14,
      name: "org1-2"
    }, {
      name: "org1-3",
      count: 6
    }]
  }, {
    name: "si2",
    count: 22,
    children: [{
      name: "org2-1",
      count: 22
    }]
  }]
}]

function getData(input, number){
    let len = input.length;
    let ans = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if(input[i].count >= number){
            if(input[i].children){
                let data = getData(input[i].children,number);
            //ans.push(input[i]);
            input[i].children = data;
            ans.push(input[i])
            }
            else{
                ans.push(input[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
getData(businessList,10)
getData(businessList,23)
```

above function should work

Comment: Oh damn use forEach or map

Comment: @Alex I avoid for each or map bacuse there would be more function call other than recursion which might effect stack

Comment: Your code will produce wrong answer as the logic should be `count>givenNumber` not `count>=givenNumber` as mentioned in the question. for `getData(input, 10)` there should be no item with count = 10.

Comment: @sabbir.alam thanks for pointing it out, I assumed those things can be handled once logic is clear

Comment: Besides this code will not scale if there are more than 2 level of nested children.

Comment: @sabbir.alam it should work for any level of nesting as I am calling it recursively

Comment: My bad. Sorry didn't notice the recursive call of getData. :)

Comment: Abhishek and sabbir solution are similar. I don't see any performance difference here. however sabbir's solution is more clean.

Comment: @JustRaman  if you look call stack size then sabbir stack size will be more I think.